# How to call a function soon after other function execution is completed in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i have two functions named function_1 and function_2. only when function_1 is done executing function_2 should start executing..How can i call function_2 only after function_1 completed in es6 syntax?

Below is the code,

```
this.function_1();
this.function_2();// this should be called soon after function_1 is done
```

What i have tried,

```
 this.function_1(()=> {
    this.function_2();}
    );
```

But the above doesnt seem working. Could someone help me solving this. thanks.

Comment: `this.function_1(()=> {` should be `this.function_1 = () => {`

Comment: Promises are a nice way to handle callbacks: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: Could you show the code of those functions?

Comment: If `function1` is synchronous, then you are already good to go. However, if there is asynchronous behavior in `function1` then you should define it as `async` and then `await` the async behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All else being equal, your first code block is all you need:

```
this.function_1();
this.function_2();
```

Now, it is possible that `function_1` might trigger something asynchronous so *things* happen after `function_1` is technically *done*.

If you want to run `function_2` after all those things are finished, then `function_1` must **explicitly** provide a mechanism to allow that.

---

The **traditional** approach is for `function_1` to accept a callback, which case this would work:

```
this.function_1(()=> {
    this.function_2();
});
```

The **modern** approach is for `function_1` to return a promise, in which case this would work:

```
this.function_1()
    .then(()=> {
        this.function_2();
    });
```

MDN has [detailed information about Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

It would also allow you to use `await` syntax *providing* you were inside a function declared with the `async` keyword.

```
async function myFunction() {
    await this.function_1();
    this.function_2();
}
```

MDN has detailed information about [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

---

Finally, to repeat my earlier point for emphasis: `function_1` must explicitly enable either of these approaches for them to work.

Comment: thanks. but the modern approach u mentioned doesnt work.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user — It does if `function_1` implements promises correctly.

Comment: could you tell me how to use it with promises. for now its just a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises, and additionally you could use async await

```js
function f1 () {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(console.log('f1')), 1000));
}

function f2() {
  console.log('f2');
}

async function f3() {
  await f1();
  f2();
}

f1().then(f2);
// or with async await syntax
f3();
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering function_1 does some async action. You can achieve this using simple callback.

You can pass the function_2 to as a callback to function_1.
It tells function_1 that, once it has completed its execution, it should call the execute the callback function.

Check this out.

```js
function function_1(callback) {
  console.log('function_1');
  // Do some time consuming action.
  // Below setTimeout is just for demo purpose
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, 1000)
}

function function_2() {
  console.log('function_2');
}

function_1(function_2);
```